# My meta tags aren't noticed on Twitter or Facebook share cards

Tags: html, facebook, twitter, share, meta-tags

I've added all the required meta tags to my html head section but when I run my site through Twitter Card Validator or another site like opengraph.dev, my tags cannot be found.

The Twitter Card Validator log tells me, "ERROR: Fetching the page failed because other errors.".

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, everything is as it supposed to be on my end. This is so frustrating!

Here's my head section:

```
<!-- Primary Meta Tags -->
<title>Web | DASA</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="author" content="DASA">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1" />
<meta name="description" content="Web | DASA is a a full-service web design and development company that specializes in creating custom websites that are tailored to the needs and goals of our clients.">
<!-- Open Graph / Facebook -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://dasa.rf.gd/">
<meta property="og:title" content="Web | DASA">
<meta property="og:description" content="Web | DASA is a a full-service web design and development company that specializes in creating custom websites that are tailored to the needs and goals of our clients.">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://dasa.rf.gd/images/DASA_1000.png">
<!-- Google Verification -->
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="DT_07_6QW8E0XDtntVY_u5nDz8OFjlgGg9lKnd6uPiU" />

<!-- Twitter -->
<meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://dasa.rf.gd//">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="Web | DASA">
<meta property="twitter:description" content="Web | DASA is a a full-service web design and development company that specializes in creating custom websites that are tailored to the needs and goals of our clients.">
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://dasa.rf.gd/images/DASA_1000.png">
```

Here's the url for my site: https://dasa.rf.gd

Comment: When I request information for your meta content URIs I am seeing `request to https://dasa.rf.gd/ failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate`. This might be a part of a larger issue with your certs. The response to this open issue might help you: [GitHub Open Issue Ref](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6354#issuecomment-487568482)

Comment: From what I can find your TLS Certificate is not trusted since it is not signed by a trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store).

Comment: Since you are using [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/) I would probably recommend [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) instead but that is just one of many options.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are there any other alternatives you know of besides Let's Encrypt? I'm using InfinityFree and they don't support Let's Encrypt anymore. I tried using GoGetSSL but that gives me the same result.

Comment: Also, how is it that the certificate is not trusted when browsers like Firefox and Chrome shows it to be trusted?

Comment: FIx the Chain issues that are listed on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=dasa.rf.gd&latest and I think it will work

Comment: That's an awesome tool @WizKid. c.dasa I take back what I said I believe WizKid is right.

Comment: This might help if you are wondering how to fix the chain issue: [_"If the analysis found problems related to your certificate chain, your intermediate certificate (in ZeroSSL, the file is called ca_bundle.crt) might be missing or invalid"_](https://zerossl.com/help/troubleshoot/missing-intermediate-certificate)

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. The chain issue was indeed the problem. I switched to Let's Encrypt and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can occur when your TLS certificate is signed by an untrusted authority. Specifically, the intermediate certificate in the certificate chain may be missing or invalid.

You can use a service like [SSL Labs Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) to identify issues with your certificates and follow their recommendations to resolve the problem. Additionally, you can look up your certificate provider's FAQ or documentation if the issues persists.

Since you are using [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/), a quick recommendation will be to switch to [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) as their intermediate certificates are signed by the [Internet Security Research Group](https://www.abetterinternet.org/)